# Why does it say 'unexpected end of input'?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
<script>
function convert(x){
 return(5/9)*(x-32);
 var x = document.forms["myForm"]["box"].value;
 if (x == "") {
  alert("Name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =x;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
 Farenheit:<br>
 <input type="text" id="box"/><br>
 <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="convert()"/>
</form>
<p id="answer"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

It says 'unexpected end of input after  =x;
I'm new to javascript so it might just be an easy mistake. The point of this is to convert farenheit to celcius.
The return(5/9)*(x-32);  is the equation to convert it.

Comment: You're missing your closing `}` for your `function`

Comment: Once you fix the syntax error, you'll find that no part of your code actually updates `answer` - you will need to rearrange some things, because right now the "answer" is set when the page loads but never again.

Comment: Thanks! But the code still doesn't work and display the converted numer? Do you know why?

Comment: The very first thing you do is return from the function...

Comment: Thanks once again but who do I update the code once i press submit?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before continuing.

Comment: Your function makes no sense since it returns before it can ever read anything else in the function.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an end paranthesis.

```
<script>
function convert(x){
 return(5/9)*(x-32);
 var x = document.forms["myForm"]["box"].value;
 if (x == "") {
  alert("Name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =x;
}
</script>
```

Should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were looking for:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fahrenheit to Celsius converter</title>
<script>
function convert(x)
{
 var x = document.forms.myForm.box.value;
 if (x === "") // keep in mind the case of 0
 {
   alert("Farenheit box must be filled out");
   return false;
 }
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Celsius " + (5/9)*(x-32);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
 Farenheit:<br>
 <input type="text" name="box"><br>
 <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="convert()">
</form>
<p id="answer"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Fixes the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two opening curly brackets "{", and only one closing "}"